# Creating a SQL Query with two tables

Tags: sql

I need some assistance creating a query for the following result:

[image]

I currently have two tables Accounts, which lists the users and how much they initial owe and Payments, which holds all the records of the payments the users have made. I know how to merge tables with JOIN but I don't know how to do the math needed to get the owed amount and paid amounts.

The columns in Accounts consist of: ID, Name, Account, Borrowed
The columns in Payments consist of: ID, AcctID, PaymentAmt

I need a query that will combine both of these tables and do the math to show how much the user has currently paid and how much the user still owes from the initial borrowed amount.

***Example Table data:***

#### ACCOUNTS TABLE

ID = 3, Name = Joe, Account = Business, Borrowed = 100.00

#### PAYMENTS TABLE

ID = 1, AcctID = 3, PaymentAmt = 10.00
ID = 2, AcctID = 3, PaymentAmt = 10.00

I am using MS SQL in C#.

Comment: Looks like some homework ...

Comment: @Pure.Krome: Good homework questions are welcome, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/147100/the-homework-tag-is-now-officially-deprecated

Comment: @Pure.Krome I'm far too old to be doing homework. Trying to learn SQL and C# for my job.

Comment: Well, glad you got your answer :) Welcome to SO :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You just need to join and then use SUM and GROUP BY.

```
SELECT a.Name ,
       a.Account ,
       a.Borrowed  - COALESCE(SUM(p.PaymentAmt),0) as [Still Owes],
       COALESCE(SUM(p.PaymentAmt),0) as Paid,
       a.Borrowed
FROM  
       ACCOUNTS  a
       LEFT JOIN PAYMENTS p
       ON a.ID = p.AcctID 
GROUP BY
       a.Name ,
       a.Account ,
       a.Borrowed
```

Note that I did a LEFT JOIN in the case no payments were made. This also requires the use of COALESCE to convert Null SUMs to 0

[DEMO](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1a61d/2)

Comment: Okay, now say I wanted to gather the total amount owed by all users. So referencing my image in my original post I need a query that will get me the number 655.00 (80+500+50+25). Any idea on how to accomplish this?

Comment: @kcray as another row or column?

Comment: just that value alone with no other values, a query that would just grab that number.

Comment: It's pretty much the same. Just drop the `Group By ` clause. Remove everything from the select clause. And wrap sum around borrowed [like so](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/1a61d/7)

Comment: That didn't seem to work for me, I added a few more records to the Payments table and it threw the number way off. [look here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fb7a9/1/0)

Comment: @kcray doh! Yeah that's not going to work. You're going to need to use Lamak's approach and sum the values from payments to get a single value per accounts and then so the calculation [see here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/ef579/7)

Comment: You my friend are the best, thank you very much. That worked great and I'm learning so much. Thanks again for all your time and help. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

This should do:

```
SELECT  A.[Name], 
        A.Account,
        A.Borrowed - ISNULL(P.Paid,0) [Still Owes],
        ISNULL(P.Paid,0) Paid,
        A.Borrowed
FROM Accounts A
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT  AcctID,
                    SUM(PaymentAmt) Paid
            FROM Payments 
            GROUP BY AcctID) P
    ON A.ID = P.AcctID
```

Answer (score 0):

```
select  a.Name
,       a.Account
,       a.Borrowed - coalesce(sum(p.PaymentAmt),0) as [Still Owes]
,       coalesce(sum(p.PaymentAmt),0) as Paid
,       a.Borrowed
from    Accounts a
left join
        Payments p
on      p.AcctID = a.ID
group by
        a.Name
,       a.Account
,       a.Borrowed
```